# Save state of viewpager fragment in navigation drawer fragments

Tags: android, navigation, fragment, drawer

I have Navigation drawer.and in First fragmant of Navigation drawer there is viewpager and there is information coming from network.Viewpager has 2 fragments also.When I switch fragment to Settings fragment of navigation drawer and coming back to this fragment everything is gone..There is no any information..How can i save state of this fragment?Or in which method can i send request to take information from network again

MainActivity

```
          public class MainActivity extends AppCompatActivity implements 

        NavigationView.OnNavigationItemSelectedListener {

        private DrawerLayout drawer;

@Override

protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {

    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);

    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);


    NavigationView navigationView = (NavigationView) findViewById(R.id.nav_view);
    navigationView.setNavigationItemSelectedListener(this);

    getSupportFragmentManager()
            .beginTransaction()
            .replace(R.id.motherFragments, FragmentMainPage.newInstance("MainPage"))
            .commit();
}

@Override
public void onBackPressed() {
   drawer = (DrawerLayout) findViewById(R.id.drawer_layout);
    if (drawer.isDrawerOpen(GravityCompat.START)) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    } else {
        super.onBackPressed();
    }
}

@Override
public boolean onCreateOptionsMenu(Menu menu) {
    // Inflate the menu; this adds items to the action bar if it is present.
    getMenuInflater().inflate(R.menu.main, menu);
    return true;
}

@Override
public boolean onOptionsItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    switch (item.getItemId()) {
        case android.R.id.home: {
            drawer.openDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
            break;
        }

    }

    return super.onOptionsItemSelected(item);
}

@SuppressWarnings("StatementWithEmptyBody")
@Override
public boolean onNavigationItemSelected(MenuItem item) {
    Fragment fragment = null;

    if (item.isChecked()) {
        drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
        return false;
    }
    switch (item.getItemId()) {

        case R.id.home: {
            fragment = new FragmentMainPage().newInstance("Sample");
            break;
        }
        case R.id.settings:{
            Intent intent = new Intent(this,SettingsActivity.class);
            startActivity(intent);
            break;
        }
        case R.id.incoming:{
            fragment  = new FragmentIncomingPage().newInstance("Sample");
            break;
        }

    }

    if (fragment != null) {
        getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction().replace(R.id.motherFragments, fragment)
                .commit();
        item.setChecked(true);

    }

    drawer.closeDrawer(GravityCompat.START);
    return true;
} }
```

Fragment1 of Navigation drawer

```
            public class FragmentMainPage extends Fragment implements 
         ViewPager.OnPageChangeListener {
             private Toolbar toolbar;
              private MainActivity activity;
           private TabLayout tabLayout;
             private ViewPager viewPager;

String[] names = {
        "Sample 1",
        "Sample 2"

};



private static FragmentMainPage myInstance;
public static FragmentMainPage newInstance(String testString){
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("test",testString);
    if(myInstance == null){
        myInstance = new FragmentMainPage();
    }
    myInstance.setArguments(bundle);
    return myInstance;
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    activity = ((MainActivity) context);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_fragment_main,container,false);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

    activity.setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    activity.setTitle(getResources().getText(R.string.bosh_sahifa));
    activity.getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_menu_white_24dp);
    activity.getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);
    viewPager = (ViewPager) view.findViewById(R.id.viewpager);
    setupViewpager(viewPager);
    tabLayout = (TabLayout) view.findViewById(R.id.tabs);
    tabLayout.setupWithViewPager(viewPager);
    viewPager.addOnPageChangeListener(this);
    setupTabName();

    return view;
}


private void setupViewpager(ViewPager viewPager) {
    MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager());
    adapter.addFragement(new Fragment_home1());
    adapter.addFragement(new Fragment_home2());

    viewPager.setAdapter(adapter);

}

private void setupTabName() {
    tabLayout.getTabAt(0).setText(names[0]);
    tabLayout.getTabAt(1).setText(names[1]);

}

@Override
public void onSaveInstanceState(Bundle outState) {
    super.onSaveInstanceState(outState);


}

@Override
public void onPageScrolled(int position, float positionOffset, int positionOffsetPixels) {

}

@Override
public void onPageSelected(int position) {

}

@Override
public void onPageScrollStateChanged(int state) {

}

private class MyAdapter extends FragmentPagerAdapter {
    private final List<Fragment> mFragmentList = new ArrayList<>();

    public MyAdapter(FragmentManager fm) {
        super(fm);
    }

    @Override
    public Fragment getItem(int position) {
        return mFragmentList.get(position);
    }

    @Override
    public int getCount() {
        return mFragmentList.size();
    }
    public void addFragement(Fragment fragment){
        mFragmentList.add(fragment);
    }
}
```

}

Fragment 2 of Navigation drawer

```
             public class FragmentIncomingPage extends Fragment  {
             private Toolbar toolbar;
               private MainActivity activity;




private static FragmentIncomingPage myInstance;
public static FragmentIncomingPage newInstance(String testString){
    Bundle bundle = new Bundle();
    bundle.putString("test",testString);
    if(myInstance == null){
        myInstance = new FragmentIncomingPage();
    }
    myInstance.setArguments(bundle);
    return myInstance;
}

@Override
public void onAttach(Context context) {
    super.onAttach(context);
    activity = ((MainActivity) context);
}

@Override
public void onCreate(@Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setHasOptionsMenu(true);
}

@Nullable
@Override
public View onCreateView(LayoutInflater inflater, @Nullable ViewGroup container, @Nullable Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    View view = inflater.inflate(R.layout.activity_fragment_incoming,container,false);
    toolbar = (Toolbar) view.findViewById(R.id.toolbar);

    activity.setSupportActionBar(toolbar);
    activity.setTitle(getResources().getText(R.string.Incoming));
    activity.getSupportActionBar().setHomeAsUpIndicator(R.drawable.ic_menu_white_24dp);
    activity.getSupportActionBar().setDisplayHomeAsUpEnabled(true);

    return view;
}
```

}

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have 3 fragments and swipe to 3rd fragment then back to 1st fragment, the 1st fragment's data is gone?

Comment: If your situation is what i mentioned above, please try `ViewPager.setOffscreenPageLimit(2)`

Comment: No in viewpager i can use more fragments..It is working fine...When i change mother fragment of viewpager and coming back to this mother fragment everything is gone..

Comment: Can you post some code snipe about 'When i change mother fragment of viewpager' and  code snipe of 'coming back'

Comment: So you open Fragment1 and then open Fragment2, finally reopen Fragment1, the data of fragment1 is gone?

Comment: yeah sure it is..Data of viewpager fragments is gone

Comment: I write a demo about switching two fragments to see if `Fragment.onCreate()`,`Fragment.onCreateView()` methods are called, and find that both of them are called. If your network request is send in them, everything should be ok. Maybe you should print log in `Fragment.onDestory()` and `Fragment.onDestroyView()` to see whether this fragment is destroyed or `Fragment`'s View is destoryed. And also you should print log in `ViewPager`'s fragment to see if the network is sended. Wait for your reply.

Comment: Another sugesstion is that use `getChildFragmentManager()` in fragment to  get FragmentManager and pass it to `ViewPager`'s `Adapter`. I guess this is the key point of your problem.

Comment: I don't understand..Can you change and show it in my code and paste it here

Comment: At beginning, i think it's the question of fragment lifecycle. When `Fragment` is detach from `Activity`, the `Fragment` will be destroyed along with it's view. `getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction().replace(R.id.motherFragments, fragment)` will make previous fragment detach from `Activity`, and your Fragment1 will be destroyed(including it's view).

Comment: When `getSupportFragmentManager()
                .beginTransaction().replace(R.id.motherFragments, fragment1)` re-replaced, your Fragment1 will start from `Fragment.onCreate()`-`Fragment.onCreateView()`-`Fragment.onViewCreated()`, so i said it was ok if pre Fragment1 was destroyed, it will be recreated and network request will be resend in `Fragment.onViewCreated` or `Fragment.onCreateView`.

Comment: You use `MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager());` to display child fragment. `getActivity().getSupportFragmentManager()` returns activity's fragment manager  which belongs to activity.The `Activity` manages fragments and fragments's stack via this manager. If fragment has sub fragment, you should use `getChildFragmentManager()` to get the fragment's manager, parent fragment use it to manage it's sub fragments. So you can try `MyAdapter adapter = new MyAdapter(getChildFragmentManager());`

Comment: Thank you a lot my friend..I did it finally with your help..It is working fine now....

Comment: I'm curious what went wrong, and how you fixed it :)

Answer (score 0):

You can use **fragment.addToBackStack(null)** method.
like,

```
FragmentTransaction ft = getSupportFragmentManager().beginTransaction();
ft.replace(R.id.content_frame, A);
ft.addToBackStack(null);
ft.commit();
```

Comment: where i use it?In drawer Fragment or In MainActivity which switches drawer fragments.?

Comment: @JavohirRuzimurodov When you replace or add your fragment use above code.

Comment: I did as you said..but it still looses data

Answer (score 0):

There is few ways to achieve it.

1. You can use SharedPreferences to save current Fragment by mViewPager.getCurrentItem() and set it again once you come to the ViewPager activity by navigation drawer button.
2. Use BaseFragment and implement your fragments from the Base Fragment, keep current visible fragment of the view pager in side the Base Fragment as protected variable.
3. As Base Fragment which is describe above, You can use Bas Activity class.